# What is an easy way to connect to SSL VPN (Windows) from Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: windows, vpn, ubuntu-10.10

I found some (presumably old) steps here, but there has got to be an easier way!

http://david.dw-perspective.org.uk/da/index.php/computer-resources/juniper-networks-ssl-vpn-client-on-linux/

Right now, when I go to a network manager / VPN, I do not have an option for Windows; only Cisco (vpnc) and PPTP. Please help; let me know if there any any questions.

Comment: are you able to go to Java.com and verify your java install?

Comment: @Kyle, Your Java version is Version 6 Update 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows VPN is PPTP, so you're looking for a PPTP client on Ubuntu - fortunately one is built in.

[This guide](http://computergyan.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/out-of-the-box-support-for-pptp-vpn-in-ubuntu-10-04/) is slightly thin on details but should be relevant. [This forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1628495) also looks relevant. The summary seems to be (and I haven't done this so I can't confirm it):

1. Left click on the network manager and select vpn-> configure vpn .
2. Add the credentials of your network.
3. Click on advanced settings, select point-to-point encryption (MPPE) and ‘Allow stateful encryption’.
4. Uncheck the rest of the options and save the settings.

Comment: +1 Perfect! It was still somewhat of a pain because steps 1 through 4 did not match exactly what I did. It was more like 6 steps and slightly different, but this did work!

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to install Java and don't mind using a web-based VPN you could try this:
http://www.subvs.co.uk/ssl_vpn_on_ubuntu

I'm not sure if this method is more 'simple' than your other option but it does require less software.

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the links there are dead. I have a 64-bit version of Ubuntu 10.10. Would you kindly guide me through the installation?

Comment: @fantomas make sure you install 64 bit java.

Comment: Try this: http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.ubuntu-fr.org%2Fssl-explorer&act=url but instead of installing Java 5 install Java 6

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://joernfranz.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/vpn-in-ubuntu-10-10/) is a tutorial for setting up a VPN in Ubuntu 10.10.

There's also [OpenVPN](http://vpnblog.info/ubuntu1010-openvpn-strongvpn.html).

Comment: Well, I have it installed. What is next? How do I connect to a Windows VPN?
$ openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.1.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [PF_INET6] [eurephia] built on Jul 12 2010
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2009 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>

Comment: Um, I'm not sure I understand your question. If the package is already installed, just go ahead and set up the VPN connection. There are pictures on the linked tutorials. You will need to contact the VPN's administrator for server info and login credentials if you don't already have them.